# Yandex Map Kit Android

Tags: android, yandex-maps-api

Впринципе я уже не раз работал с мапкитом яндекса для андроида.
Но сейчас возникла немного непростая задача решения которой еше не нашел.
Можем ли мы закрепить неподвижный маркер по центру карты и юзеру оставить возможность двигать карту, а нам получить текущие координаты маркера.

Comment: Можете ли скинуть пример имплементации вашего решения?

Comment: Удалось ли найти решение средствами МапКита? Или пришлось отображать пин поверх карты и брать координаты центра карты?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это можно сделать добавлением маркера не на карту, а просто поверх карты, а потом переводить координаты экрана в координаты карты :) 
Мне кажется так будет правильней.